# CakePHP var $useTable = false still produces "Base table or view not found: 1146 ..." error

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0

I can't work this one out and I'd rather not have to fill my controller with unBinds. I have a sage pay form which needs validating. Therefore I set up a sage model with the following:

```
class Sage extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = false;
    var $_schema = array(
        'CardHolderName'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'CardType'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'CardNumber'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'EndMonth'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'EndYear'       =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_address_line_1'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_city'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_county'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_country'       =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_country'       =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'BILLING_post_code'     =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_name'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_address_line_1'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_city'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_county'        =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_country'       =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'DELIVER_post_code'     =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
        'CSV'       =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>3)

    );

    public $validate = array(
        'CardHolderName'=>array(
            'Please enter your name.'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please enter your name.'
            )
        ),
        'CardType'=>array(
            'Card Type Select'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'You must select a card type.'
            )
        ),
        'CardNumber'=>array(
            'Card Number Length'=>array(
                'rule'=> array('between', 16, 20),
                'message'=>'Card numbers are at least 16 numbers long.'
            ),
            'Not empty'=>array(
                'rule'=> 'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Card Number is missing.'
            ),
            'Is a number' => array(
                'rule' => 'numeric',
                'message' => 'This must be a number (no spaces either).'
            )
        ),
        'EndMonth'=>array(
            'End Month Select'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'No Month.'
            )
        ),
        'EndYear'=>array(
            'End Year Select'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'No Year.'
            )
        ),
        'CSV'=>array(
            'Card Number Length'=>array(
                'rule'=> array('between', 3, 3),
                'message'=>'A CSV is 3 numbers long.'
            ),
            'CSV not empty'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please enter your security code.'
            ),
            'Is a number' => array(
                'rule' => 'numeric',
                'message' => 'A CSV is 3 numbers long.'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But when I go to my order's index page (which has a `$this->paginate('Order');` in there) I get the following:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'wr_shop.sages' doesn't exist
>
> SQL Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `wr_shop`.`orders` AS
>   `Order` LEFT JOIN `wr_shop`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Order`.`user_id` =
>   `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `wr_shop`.`baskets` AS `Basket` ON
>   (`Basket`.`order_id` = `Order`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `wr_shop`.`sages` AS
>   `Sage` ON (`Sage`.`order_id` = `Order`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

Can someone tell me what I have missed, I can't seem to find the answer online anywhere.

---UPADATE--- I've temp fixed the issue by creating a 'sages' table even though it will never hold any data.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Cake by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sage model is not loaded correctly, an AppModel instance is used instead.

Check the path, filename and file extension: app/Model/Sage.php

Comment: The path and file are correct, the only way I can make it happy is to have an empty 'sages' database despite having var $useTable = false;

Comment: Thanks for answering by the way no one else did.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same issue, in my case the problem was that my form sent the ID field. When I removed the ID field the validation was performed well.